# display one array randomly on other array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I need to display one array randomly on other array.

For example : I need to display `$advertises` on `$abc` but It is displaying many post.

```
$args =array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'OR',
                        array(
                             'key'  => 'to_event_date',
                             'value' => date('Y/m/d'),
                             'type'  => 'date',
                             'compare'=>'>=',
                         ),
            'relation'=>'OR',
                        array(
                             'key'  => 'to_event_date',
                             'value' => '',
                             'compare'=>'=',
                        )
         )
);

$test = query_posts( $args );

 $advertise1 = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'post_type' => 'advertise',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
               );

 $advertises=get_posts($advertise1);
 $rand_position=rand(0,2);

 foreach($advertises as $mpost){
    $advertise=$mpost;
 }
 array_splice($test, $rand_position, 0, $advertise);
```

Somebody help me?

Comment: I need to display $advertises on $test

Answer (score 1):

This code is fine :

```
$args =array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'OR',
                        array(
                             'key'  => 'to_event_date',
                             'value' => date('Y/m/d'),
                             'type'  => 'date',
                             'compare'=>'>=',
                         ),
            'relation'=>'OR',
                        array(
                             'key'  => 'to_event_date',
                             'value' => '',
                             'compare'=>'=',
                        )
         )
);

$test = query_posts( $args );

 $advertise1 = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'post_type' => 'advertise',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'suppress_filters' => true
               );

 $advertises=get_posts($advertise1);
 $rand_position=rand(0,2);


 array_splice($test, $rand_position, 0, $advertises);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have solved this problem

Replace

array_splice($test, $rand_position, 0, $advertise);
to 
array_splice($test, $rand_position, 0, $advertises);